# How to create a 3d scatter plot from a npy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I am new to stack overflow. 
I'm currently trying to plot a scatter plot out of a npy array from a depth camera. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
img_array = np.load('640x480_depth_0.npy')
img_array.resize(480,640)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.linspace(0,1,640)
y = np.linspace(0,1,480)
z = img_array
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax.scatter(x, y, z)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Depth');
```

The plot I got didn't look like a scatter plot at all. 
["Scatter" Plot I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClAC4.png)
What should I change to make it work correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to share the image you get, and use it to explain what is wrong and what you would expect instead?

Comment: Just uploaded the image I got.

Comment: So you would like to have smaller scatter points? I.e `ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=1)`?

Comment: The scanning data have an object placed on a flat surface in the middle but the scatter plot doesn't show any shape of the object so I am not sure which step went wrong.

Comment: Hard to find out without the actual file. What does `print(len(np.unique(img_array)))` give?